# arithmatic operators as a function input (C++)

Tags: c++, c++17

Let's say I have a function

```
#include <iostream>
int do_math (num_1, num_2, "*"){
....
}
```

Where the code takes the inputs and applies the operator in the function to obtain the result of the calculation.

I'm not sure how to incorporate the arithmetic operator in the function to do the calculation. I was thinking of using the operator value from the ASCII table, but I was hoping maybe I can somehow incorporate istringstream method to do that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `char` type for the operator and check it in the `switch`.

For example:

```
int do_math( const int a, const int b, const char op )
{
    switch ( op )
    {
    case '+':
        return a + b;

    // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It can be done as well through templates

```
template<typename Input, typename BinaryOp>
auto do_math(Input a, Input b, BinaryOp op)
{
   return op(a,b);
}
```

This can be called like so:

```
auto res = do_math(5, 4, std::plus<int>());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lambda` for any arbitrary operation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

template<typename T, typename F>
auto do_math(T a, T b, F&& op)
{
    return op(a, b);
}

int main() {
    auto ans = do_math(5, 4, [](int x, int y) -> int { return x+y; });
    std::cout << ans << std::endl;
    auto ans2 = do_math(5, 4, [](int x, int y) -> int { return std::pow(x, y); });
    std::cout << ans2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```